# Take specific number of records per each supplied Id

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How would one write a query to take 5 records per each supplied ID?
Let's say I have 5 comments, and I want to load 5 replies, and a total reply count for each comment.

Something like

```
select ReplyId, ReplyContent, COUNT(*) TotalCount 
from Replies R 
where R.CommentId in (1,2,3,4,5)
Order By R.PublishDate Desc
TAKE 5, for each id
```

Desired result would be a data set with a maximum of 50 records in this case. A 5 or less replies for each comment, and total number of replies  for each comment.

Comment: Please format your code so it's easy to read, even if it's pseudocode. A long line that requires scrolling isn't very readable

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` for example:

```
SELECT ReplyId, ReplyContent, TotalCount
FROM
(
SELECT 
  CommentId,
  ReplyId, 
  ReplyContent, 
  COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY R.CommentId) TotalCount,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY R.CommentId ORDER BY R.PublishDate DESC) row_n
FROM 
  Replies R where R.CommentId in (1,2,3,4,5)
) t
WHERE t.row_n <= 5
```